# Drive says it's full when it is not

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, ext3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't Ubuntu see any free space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5130/why-cant-ubuntu-see-any-free-space)

I have a hard drive that should have close to 40GB free. However, when I just restarted the computer, Ubuntu popped up with the notification stating that the drive has 0 bytes of space remaining.

When I run `df -h` I get the following output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc5             721G  684G     0 100% /media/Storage1
```

As you can tell, 684G + 0GB != 721GB, instead I should have 37GB available.

Running `fsck /dev/sdc5` showed that there are no problems and nothing was recovered on the ext3 mount.

Where did my missing 30GB go? How can I get them back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds  like the 5% reservation for the root user. You can change that with

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sdc5
```

to 1% like in this example. If it is just a storage partition 0% should be OK too.

Answer (score 2):

By default 5% on a ext3 file system are reserved for root. You can change this using

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdc5
```