# bash: echo: write error: No space left on device

Tags: bash

I am using Ubuntu Linux and using this as PHP server hosting the scripts and sites in `/var/www/`. I am getting `bash: echo: write error: No space left on device` but there is huge space left on the device. I have found on google about this issue but no one suits my problem as people were getting this error after running some commands but I am getting it just after running `gksudo nautilus` yesterday,

I am unable to umount any drive please suggest me what to do

I have run `$ sudo apt-get clean`

I have run `$ sudo apt-get autoremove`

I am getting this message after running `$ df -k

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7       93956704  89329640         0 100% /
udev             1989324         4   1989320   1% /dev
tmpfs             799256      1076    798180   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1998132      3324   1994808   1% /run/shm
overflow            1024        16      1008   2% /tmp
/dev/sda2      240367612 192464952  47902660  81% /media/CE48787148785A63
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

when running `$ df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        90G   86G     0 100% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           781M  1.1M  780M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  3.3M  2.0G   1% /run/shm
overflow        1.0M   16K 1008K   2% /tmp
/dev/sda2       230G  184G   46G  81% /media/CE48787148785A63
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

after running disk free command with -k and -h flags. It is clear that My device has ample space to work on. If someone has resolved the same issue please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't Ubuntu see any free space?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5130/why-cant-ubuntu-see-any-free-space)

Comment: /dev/sda7 - Use 100%
Give the exact path where you want to write, is it sda2 or sda7?

Comment: Look at the evidence.  Root is full (100%) for non-privileged processes.  Compare `df /` and `sudo df /`.  First place to look would be `/var/log`

Comment: Your root  filesystem is full.  That's what the line starting with /dev/sda7 telld you.

Comment: It is sda7 Xylo

Comment: I do not think that the suggested duplicate really is a duplicate. It does not deal with exactly the same problem, viz. how come the numbers don't change after having deleted files.

Comment: Have you unmouted `/media/CE48787148785A63`?

Comment: yes don.joey I have mounted `/media/CE48787148785A63`. It is my windows partition

Comment: @ChitrankDixit Thanks for your question it helped me out a lot.

Comment: @Alex welcome , Helped me too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are hitting the limit on your /dev/sda7 drive that isn't reserved. To see more about reserved space, please see:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why

To lower the amount of space reserved (looks like it is currently set at 2%), you can run the following command to lower it:

`sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda7`

Please note that the reserved space is there for a reason. This will cause issues later if you continue to use up more space.